# PHP Cookie not available if i'm using .htaccess mod rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I'm using .htaccess rewrite rules.
my rules are

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Login login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Register register.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Posts/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) posts.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [NC,L]
```

All are working perfectly but the problem is here:

If i access

```
<a href='Login'>Login</a> from website home page it is redirecting to login.php that is perfectly working
```

But If i access

```
<a href='Login'>Login</a> from website posts page it is redirecting to Posts/login.php which is incorrect. It should redirect to login.php only.
```

To solve this i used direct page in Login button as

```
<a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/Login'>Login</a>
```

its working perfectly fine but the problem is, cookies not available as i need to maintain city name in cookie in every page.

check my website links:
    http://fidfeet.com/Login, 
    http://fidfeet.com/Categories/Login

First one is working as i'm in home page, But second not working as i'm in categories page.

Comment: if you don't mind about not using cookies, you can register the city name into a session. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your links are pointing at relative paths, which is why they are not resolving to the same place from subdirectories. They should point to /Login to refer to the Login at the root.

The cookie is available at the second path after defining it from the first. There is a box in the upper right that lists my selected city.